# How to add Discount at cart page in shopify

Tags: shopify, shopping-cart

I have been trying to add discount to cart page just like added at checkout page but i  have failed to do so. I want to add it before the subtotal [Like this](https://i.imgur.com/eaXoCQv.png/). I have tried so many solutions but none of them worked for me. Each time i am getting blank in the response. I think the actual issue is either i am not getting the proper code or the type selection while we are creating the discount. I am confused about actually which type we have to use while we have to display the discount at cart page. Sharing the image of the discount types i am getting while hitting on create discount button from admin panel [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zspUR.png).

I have tried following solutions:

- [1st](https://gist.github.com/elghorfi/c1c639e97b7514cb8fcfcf5800c1a832)
- [2nd](https://community.shopify.com/c/ecommerce-marketing/show-discount-price-in-cart-page/td-p/942689)
- [3rd](https://shopify.dev/api/liquid/objects/cart#cart-cart_level_discount_applications)
- [4th](https://shopify.dev/themes/pricing-payments/discounts#cart-discounts)

and so many other solutions tried but each of them comes up with blank

Answer (score 0):

TLDR; 1st assume the discount will be applied before the page finishes loading and 3rd and 4th has nothing to do with the discount apply function.

1st solution will fail from time to time because applying a discount code is asynchronous action. That means a document that you're fetching (checkout) could finish loading but the discount does not. When the discount loads it will trigger a few custom events that will refresh the checkout.

2nd, 3rd, and 4th are used to show automatic discount values. Your requirement describes applying a discount code which is different.

2nd says:

> If you are using Automatic Discounts, like a short-term 10 % OFF ON ALL ORDERS, these discounts can be applied automatically and can be displayed on the cart page using cart_level_discount_applications in Liquid

This discount field is sometimes achieved by using Admin API together with a custom private app, but note that it's still not the best solution because in edge cases it could show incorrect values and cause poor user experience (it's slow). Developing such an app is quite expensive and hard due to all scenarios that you need to cover. Your best choice is to use paid app I guess but still, this is not something I would assume is going to always work just fine.

Comment: I can work with applying automatically also and if you are suggesting for using app then can you please suggest any app that can be helpful in showing the discount or applying the discount.

Comment: @savitanagdev so just to confirm - you would like to show an automatic discount on cart level **only**? If so, can you share the code that you have tried and is not working so we can try to fix it? Note that there could be a conflict between a discount app and native automatic discount calculation. Regarding recommended app - unfortunately, I can't recommend any paid solution on StackOverflow.